# Simple BBparser in PHP that lets you replace content outside tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, string, bbcode

I'm trying to parse strings that represent source code, something like this:

```
[code lang="html"]
  &lt;div&gt;stuff&lt;/div&gt;
[/code]
<div>stuff</div>
```

As you can see from my previous 20 questions, I tried to do it with PHP's regex functions, but ran into many problems, especially when the string is very big...

Do you guys know a BB parser class written in PHP that I can use for this, instead of regexes?

What I need it to do is:

- be able to convert all content from within `[code]` tags with html entities
- be able to run some kind of a filter (a callback function of mine) only on content outside of the `[code]` tags

thank you

edit:
**I ended up using this:**

- convert all `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to [pre] and [code]:

  ```
  str_replace(array('<pre>', '</pre>', '<code>', '</code>'), array('[pre]', '[/pre]', '[code]', '[/code]'), $content);
  ```
- get contents from between [code]..[/code] and [pre]...[/pre] and do the html entity conversion

  ```
  preg_replace_callback('/(.?)\[(pre|code)\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/\2\])?(.?)/s', 'self::specialchars', $content);
  ```

  (i stole this pattern from wordpress shortcode functions :)
- store the entity converted content in a temporary array variable, and replace the one from `$content` with a unique ID
- I can now safely run my filter on `$content`, because there's no code in it, just the ID (this filter does a strip_tags on the entire text and converts stuff like `http://blabla.com` to links)
- replace the unique IDs from `$content` with the converted code blocks from the array variable

do you think it's ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you guys know a BB parser class written in PHP that I can use for this, instead of regexes?

There's [the BBCode PECL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), but you'd need to compile it.

There's also [PEAR's HTML_BBCodeParser](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser/redirected), though I can't vouch for how effective it is.

There are also a few elsewhere, but I think they're all pretty rigid.

I don't believe that *either* of those do what you're looking for, with regard to having a callback for tag contents (and then @webarto is *totally* correct in that HTMLPurifier is the right tool to use when processing the contents).  You *might* have to write your own here.  [I've previously written about my experiences doing the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371536/php-how-do-i-remove-nested-tags-and-relocate-them-in-an-un-nested-way/5372002#5372002) that you might find helpful.

Comment: He/she can extract contents between BB code into array, replace content with something like `{1}` where number is index in array (containing code). Run custom function on string and then "return" codes, but I don't see point in allowing HTML in comment form (that was authors intention).

Comment: @webarto, BBCode content is usually highly processed, including transformations like nl2br, nuking HTML, etc.  It might be that limited pure-HTML styling is needed, and a custom tag is being introduced to permit that to happen.

Comment: Yes, I know, but @Alexandra is allowing pure HTML outside BB codes, so BB have no point here. This question is practically already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526457/php-convert-string-to-htmlentities

Comment: @Charles I am starting to think that he/she is in fact it, bot :)

Comment: no I'm not :/ well I did anyway :D, i posted the solution in my answer. I'd appreciate if you tell me what you think of it

Answer (score 2):

HTML Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/

But you are facing same issues just like in your 20 previous questions.